# Java 8 stream api how to collect List to Object

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream, collect, collectors

I have two simple class ImageEntity and ImageList

**how to collect result list ImageEntity to ImageList ?**

```
List<File> files = listFiles();
        ImageList imageList = files.stream().map(file -> {
            return new ImageEntity(
                                   file.getName(), 
                                   file.lastModified(), 
                                   rootWebPath + "/" + file.getName());
        }).collect(toCollection(???));
```

class

```
public class ImageEntity {
private String name;
private Long lastModified;
private String url;
 ...
}
```

and

```
public class ImageList {
 private List<ImageEntity> list;

 public ImageList() {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
 }

 public ImageList(List<ImageEntity> list) {
    this.list = list;
 }
 public boolean add(ImageEntity entity) {
    return list.add(entity);
 }
 public void addAll(List<ImageEntity> list) {
     list.addAll(entity);
 }

}
```

It's not an elegant solution

```
ImageList imgList = files.stream().
  .map(file -> { return new ImageEntity(file.getName(), file.lastModified(), rootWebPath + "/" + file.getName()) })
  .collect(ImageList::new, (c, e) -> c.add(e), (c1, c2) -> c1.addAll(c2));
```

It can be a solution through collectingAndThen ?

what else have any ideas?

Answer (score 18):

Since `ImageList` can be constructed from a `List<ImageEntity>`, you can use [`Collectors.collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-):

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;

ImageList imgList = files.stream()
    .map(...)
    .collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), ImageList::new));
```

On a separate note, you don't have to use the curly braces in your lambda expression.  You can use `file -> new ImageEntity(file.getName(), file.lastModified(), rootWebPath + "/" + file.getName())`

Comment: Good ! very elegant!Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you can try below also

```
ImageList imgList = new ImageList (files.stream().
  .map(file -> { return new ImageEntity(file.getName(), file.lastModified(), rootWebPath + "/" + file.getName()) })
  .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: That's really weird, how Collectors.toList() returns Object instead of list of objects. Can you explain please ?

Comment: Its an error on my part , I considered the `ImageList` as `List<Images>` . We should have something like `.collect(converttoImageList());`

Answer (score 1):

The collectingAndThen approach has the downside of creating a list and then copying it.

If you'd like something more reusable than your initial `collect` example, and that, like your example, doesn't end doing an extra copy in the `collectingAndThen` collector, you can take the three parameters of the `collect` and make a function similar to `Collectors.toList()` that collects straight to your ImageList, like this:

```
public static Collector<ImageEntity,?,ImageList> toImageList() {
    return Collector.of(ImageList::new, (c, e) -> c.add(e), (c1, c2) -> c1.addAll(c2));
}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
ImageList imgList = files.stream().
    .map(file -> new ImageEntity(file.getName(), file.lastModified(), rootWebPath + "/" + file.getName()))
    .collect(toImageList());
```